# I need to invoke a Spring Service from a java class, how to set the active profile for spring application from java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

*I need to invoke a spring service from my java class, how would i set the active profile dynamically for spring service.
here's the code

```
java code
public void abc() {
AccountDetailService service = new AccountDetailService();
service.getAccountDetails();
}
AccountDetailService
@Profile
@Log
@Component
private void getAccountDetails() {

      String filename=environment.getProperty("fileName");
      accountDaoImpl.getDetails(filename);
}
```

i have various profiles like dev,qa and prod
how would i pass active profiles from my java class when invoking spring service.*

Comment: Profiles are set when spring is started. Even if you could/can change them at Runtime this is a terrible idea.

Comment: Also, if you instantiate a class with `new AccountDetailService()`, it's not part of the Spring context (no matter what annotations you have on the class).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass any profiles to your service. Simply, create configurations for different profiles. These configurations will provide the correct service instance for given profile. Here you have an example of such configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(value = "test")
public class ServiceTestConfig
{
    @Bean 
    public Service service()
    {
        return new TestService();
    }
}
```

Create another configuration with other `@Profile` annotation and Spring will automatically create proper instances. You can set active profile in many ways, the simplest is to change the `spring.profiles.active` property in your `application.properties`. Refer to Spring documentation to learn more about profiles:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

**Update**

If you **really** need to pass your active profile to your service in runtime, you can inject `Environment` instance and call `getActiveProfiles()`. See the javadoc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html. Just keep in mind it's not the way profiles should be used in Spring. The example I provided before is considered the best practice.

Comment: i need to pass the @Profile's value =test dynamically from my java class

Comment: Well, if you really have to do that - you can use `Environment` object to get active profiles. However, that's not how profiles are intended to be used. My original answer shows the "best practice". Anyway, I'll update my answer.